# How to split the string in python and repeat it and join

Tags: python, list

My Code is below. I want to count the letters in the output

s = string and n is number of times to repeat. n = 10, means the string s = "aba" is repeated over the course of 10 letters. i.e abaabaabaa.

```
s, n = input().strip(), int(input().strip())
print(s.count("a")
```

Out  = `7`

my code is below

```
a = 'aba'
t = list(a)
n = 3
new_list = []
if n  <=  len(t):
    for i in range(n):
        new_list.append(t[i])
        m = t + new_list
    print (''.join(m))
elif n > len(t):
    x,y = divmod(n,len(t))
    if y == 0:
        new_list.append(a * x)
    else:
        new_list.append((a * x) + ''.join(map(str,t[:y])))
```

if n is large then need to loop like len(list(s)) = 3, if n = 10, divide 10/3 and we got 3 equal part and we got 1 remainder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```py
def repeat_n(s, n):
  return (s * (n // len(s) + 1))[:n]

s = 'aba'
print(repeat_n(s, 2))
# ab

print(repeat_n(s, 10))
# abaabaabaa

print(repeat_n(s, 12))
# abaabaabaaba
```

`n // len(s)` gives you the number of times we can repeat `s` and stay below `n` characters so `n // len(s) + 1` is the number of time we can repeat `s` to get at least `n` characters (plus potentially some others).

With that number we just repeat the string with `s * (n // len(s) + 1)` and then take the first `n` characters `(s * (n // len(s) + 1))[:n]`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: fixed for python 3

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: I assume python 3 then, use // instead: `return (s * (n // int(len(s)) + 1))[:n]`

Answer (score 1):

In case the ultimate intention is to iterate over the generated string rather than directly printing it as output, an alternative is to use the `itertools` library.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

s = "aba"
n = 10
for c in islice(cycle(s), n):
    ... do other stuff ...
```

Another scenario is that you try to compare the generated string with another string `s2` of length `n`. In that case, `islice` can be omitted.

```
for c, c2 in zip(cycle(s), s2):  # zip() truncates cycle(s) to the same length as s2
     ... operate on c and c2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is modulo (`%`) operator:

```
s = 'aba'
n = 10

out = ''
for i in range(n):
    out += s[i % len(s)]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
abaabaabaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, using the `*` operator for strings:

```
s = 'aba'
n = 10

out = (s * (n // len(s)))[:n]
print(out)
```

Breaking it down:

```
n // len(s) => This is just the number of whole times s will need to be repeated
+ 1        => We add one to this, so our string will be a little longer than needed
s *        => This repeats s that number of times
[:n]       => Takes the first n characters of the string
```

So while it isn't as readable, it's very fast. Compared to the accepted answer:

```
def original_calc():
  out = ''
  for i in range(n):
    out += s[i % len(s)]
  result = out

def new_calc():
    result = (s * (n // len(s)))[:n]

import timeit
s = 'aba'
n = 10
>>> timeit.timeit(original_calc, number=100000)
0.20508930005598813
>>> timeit.timeit(new_calc, number=100000)
0.027835099957883358
```

Comment: The other answer has already mentioned about this solution and a `+1` is needed as shown to deal with the cases that `n` is not divisible by `len(s)`.

Comment: You may try comparing with `l = len(s); result = s * (n // l) + s[:n % l]` instead.